# Return a dictionary from multiple line string in swift

Tags: swift, string, dictionary

I am new to swift. Is there a simple way to convert the following string to dictionary format.

Example:

`input = "Name: Jack\\n Area: Place\\n FavColor: Blue\\n"`

Expected Output:

`dict = \[Name: Jack, Area: Place, FavColor: Blue\]`

and also leading spaces should be trimmed.

The key-value pairs are always in new line.

My idea is split the string based on new line characters first

`lines = input.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines)`

then iterate through lines and split each line based on ":" and put them into dict.

Is there any other efficient way to do it?

Comment: Your idea ideas is a good solution, but could there be a "\n" in the value? A ":"? In which case your split/components(separatedBy) might have issues (since I guess keys won't have them).

Comment: Better to use a proper string format like JSON.

Comment: It is guaranteed that both key and value is present in all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is Regular Expression, it searches for the pattern `word - colon - whitespace(s) - word` and captures both words

```
let input = "Name: Jack\n Area: Place\n FavColor: Blue\n"

let pattern = "(\\b.*\\b):\\s+(\\b.*\\b)" // or "(\\w+):\\s+(\\w+)"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
var result = [String:String]()
regex.matches(in: input).forEach { match in
    if let keyRange = Range(match.range(at: 1), in: input),
       let valueRange = Range(match.range(at: 2), in: input) {
        result[String(input[keyRange])] = String(input[valueRange])
    }
}

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

My usual approach is to split the string into an array of strings and use the position to determine if the element is a key or value. After that use stride to loop through the array two element at a time to assign the output dictionary where the first element is the key and the second element is the value.

```
let input = "Name: Jack\n Area: Place\n FavColor: Blue\n"

let charSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "\n:")
let tokenized = input.components(separatedBy: charSet).map { 
    $0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) 
}

var dict = [String : String]()
for index in stride(from: 0, to: tokenized.count - 1, by: 2) {
    dict[tokenized[index]] = tokenized[index + 1]
}
```

Comment: How do I handle the case if value itself has one more ":" in it. For example `input = "Name: Jack\n Area: Place\n FavColor: Blue\n Link: https://example.com\n"`

Comment: It’ll crash because there’ll be an odd number of elements in the resulting array. If the input are not going to be strictly the format in your initial question. If the input is going to have chars that clashes with the special characters, your best bet is to use the regex example in @vadian answer but with the regex modified to allow for “:” in the value.

Comment: The regex searches for any character within word boundaries so it parses the link correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
let input = "Name: Jack\n Area:  Place\n FavColor:   Blue\n Link:
 https://example.com".replacingOccurrences(of: " +", with: " ", options: .regularExpression, 
range: nil)

let components = input.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: ":").components(separatedBy: ": ")

var dictionary = [String:String]()

for index in stride(from: 0, to: components.count, by: 2){
        dictionary[components[index]] = components[index + 1]
}
```